# How can I require a few polyfills without requesting the whole core-js package?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, webpack-4, polyfills

So my first time asking a question here so be nice.

I'm building a webpage with react.js and a webpack 4 config and I'm trying to load polyfills dynamically through code-splitting so I can support older browsers like ie11.

I've been looking at [this](https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-split-your-chunks-with-webpack-f8a9df5b7758) tutorial for bundle splitting and code splitting.
(scroll half way down to the headline "polyfill" to get to conditionally load polyfills)

Here's my setup:

**webpack.config.js**:

```js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.html',
  filename: './index.html'
});

const cleanWebpack = new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']);


module.exports = {
  entry: ['core-js/modules/es6.promise', 'core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator', path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js')],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            minimize: true
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]',
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]'
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [cleanWebpack, htmlPlugin]
};
```

**package.json**:

```js
{
  "name": "new_portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Daniel Dahlmans portfolio site 2019",
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1% in SE",
    " not op_mini all"
  ],
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "typeface-work-sans": "0.0.54"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "debug": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

I've made a seperate file called 'polyfills.js' where I'm requiring the polyfills I need:

**polyfills.js**:

```js
require('core-js/es6/array');
require('core-js/es6/string');
require('core-js/es6/map');
require('core-js/es6/object');
require('core-js/es6/symbol');
```

I'm then importing these conditionally if they're not supported.

**index.js**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'typeface-work-sans';


const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render( < Router > < App / > < /Router>, document.getElementById('index'));
    };

    if (
      'Symbol' in window &&
      'Map' in window &&
      'startsWith' in String.prototype &&
      'endsWith' in String.prototype &&
      'includes' in String.prototype &&
      'includes' in Array.prototype &&
      'assign' in Object &&
      'entries' in Object &&
      'keys' in Object
    ) {
      render();
    } else {
      import ( /* webpackChunkName: "polyfills" */ './polyfills').then(() => {
        console.log('I am imported async');
        render();
      });
    }
```

All works well, so if I'm running my localhost in ie11 my polyfills.js is requested and if I'm in chrome it's not requested.

But to my surprise **I'm still seeing that the whole core-js package is still being requested by the browser even if I'm just requiring a few polyfills...**
and this happens in all of the browsers.

**How can I require a few polyfills without requesting the whole core-js package?**

[image - from terminal (when running devserver)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWD5K.jpg)

[image - from networks tab in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6klF.jpg)

[image - from elements tab in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REmHR.jpg)

The whole reason I'm doing this is to reduce my main.js bundle size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem like that requiring individual polyfill modules will result in a reduced bundle size, but in fact it does not.
In your package.json the entire core-js package is installed and since core-js [doesn't use ES2015 modules](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/385) Webpack can't optimize the output.

However, it's possible to create a version of core-js that only includes the modules that you need. Use core-js's [custom build tool](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/master/packages/core-js-builder) to generate a smaller bundle and add it to your code instead of entire core-js.